# Is it possible for an overloaded procedure to have a different interface from that of its parent class?

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to extend a class and overload one of its procedure with one with a different interface?

I would like to create multiple type (say `tensor1`, `tensor2`, ...) extending a base class `tensor` , all implementing a method `sub` whose arguments depend on the subclass.

Consider the following code:

```
module tensor_class
   implicit none
   private
   public :: tensor_Type

   type, abstract :: tensor_Type
   Contains
      procedure,pass(self)                             :: sub
   end type

   Contains
      subroutine sub(self,other)
         class(tensor_Type),intent(inout)              :: self
         integer                                       :: other
         write(*,*) 'sub is not implemented in the main class'
      end subroutine
end module tensor_class

module tensor1_mod
   use tensor_class

   type, extends(tensor_type)                          :: tensor1
      real,dimension(2)                                :: val
   Contains
      procedure, pass(self)                            :: sub
   end type tensor1
 Contains   
    subroutine sub(self,other)
       class(tensor1),intent(inout)                     :: self
       real,dimension(2),intent(in)                     :: other

       self%val = self%val + 2.0 * other
    end subroutine
end module

module tensor
   use tensor1_mod
end module

program testTensor
   use tensor
   implicit none 

   class(tensor_type),allocatable                      :: t
   type(tensor1)                                       :: t1
   real,dimension(2)                                   :: v1 = [1.0,-2.3]
   integer                                             :: i

   t1 = tensor1(v1)
   t  = tensor1(v1)
   call t1%sub(i)
   call t%sub(i)
end program
```

Neither Intel Fortran (19.1.1.216 20200306) nor gfortran (9.3.0) will compile it. The Intel compiler prints the following error message

```
tensorMin.F90(25): error #8383: The dummy arguments of an overriding and overridden binding that correspond by position must have the same characteristics, except for the type of the passed object dummy arguments.   [SUB]
```

and gfortran

```
>tensorMin.F90:25:15:

   25 |       procedure, pass(self)                            :: sub
      |               1
Error: Argument mismatch for the overriding procedure 'sub' at (1): Type mismatch in argument 'other' (REAL(4)/INTEGER(4))
```

I cannot declare `sub` as `deferred` in `tensor_class`, if I want to be able to create multiple subclasses and have `sub` take different type of arguments in each class (say `real, dimension(2)` in `tensor1`, `real, dimension(2,2)` in `tensor2` etc).

Upon reading of the Fortran 2008 standard section 4.5.7.3, it seems that the *name* and *number* of arguments in `sub` need to match, but the standard does not seem to say anything about the *type* of the arguments.

Am I missing something? Is there a way other than creating a class containing all possible arguments of `sub`?

Comment: "must have the same _characteristics_". The type of an argument is a characteristic. Is that the part you missed?

Comment: @francescalus That may be it indeed...
so basically I also need to create polymorphic classes for the arguments of ```sub```. I think I get it

Comment: The word "overload" is used in the question, but there is no overloading going on here - this looks like an attempt at overriding. Perhaps clarify which of those you want, because the answer to the question title is "It _must_ be different!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fortran standard does require the argument types to match.

Except for the passed-object dummy arguments the standard says that the dummy arguments which correspond shall have the same *characteristics*. (This the Intel Fortran error message states.) The type of a dummy argument is one characteristic (of many) of that argument.

You can look in to polymorphic arguments (as in your comment) or at generic bindings.